# How to manage callback functions using thread,mutex or other ways

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, boost, callback

```
void __stdcall callbackfunction(){message}

int main() {
    NotifytoServer(&callbackfunction);
    for (int i=0 ;i<3;++i) {
        AskServer();
    }

    //using messages from callbackfunction
}
```

Every time I call AskServer function,the other side(Server) will send some message to me.

1.There is a question that I don't know the times from callback function if I call AskServer(Please see the attached image).

2.How do I use some programing techs(boost::thread,mutex.etc) to wait for every time I AskServer to get messages?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use conditional variables to synchronise the threads?
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable